# Why in perl this regex is not matching line

Tags: regex, perl

I made some changes to perl code and I am not able to understand why below regular expression is not matching against the input line.

```
my $regex='^(780200703303)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+([1-9]\\d*)\\s+([1-9]\\d*)\\s+$';
my $line='780200703303    2            0            3            0            0            0            0            0            0            1 ';
if ( $line =~ m/$regex/ ) 
{
    print "Matched";
}
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: There is no need to escape backslashes inside single quotes unless you need more than one consecutive backslash or unless the backslash is the last character in the string.

Answer (score 6):

Because `0` doesn't match `[1-9]\d*`.

---

Have you considered using the following:

```
my @fields = split ' ', $line;
if ($fields[0] == 780200703303) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your test string does not match the regular expression.

```
my $regex='\\s+([1-9]\\d*)\\s+([1-9]\\d*)\\s+$';
my $line='            0            1 ';
```

`0` does not match `([1-9]\d*)`

---

Make you regex simpler by using [`qr` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

```
my $regex= qr/\s+([1-9]\d*)\s+([1-9]\d*)\s+$/;
```